# Validar que estén llenados específicos inputs antes de activar el botón de siguiente

Tags: javascript

Tengo varios inputs en mi plantilla, por ejemplo tengo estos 3 y un botón de siguiente desactivado.

Como puedo validar que solo el input de nombre y apellido estén llenos y se active el botón de siguiente. Por el momento si escribo el nombre se activa el boton, pero quiero que el nombre y apellido esten llenos y recien se active el boton de siguiente

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById("inputtext");

input.addEventListener("input", displayButton); 

function displayButton() {
  if (input.value === "") {
    b.disabled = true;
  } else {
    b.disabled = false;
  }
}

displayButton();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Nombre">
<input type="text" id="inputtext2" placeholder="Apellido">
<input type="text" id="inputtext3" placeholder="Telefono">
<button id="button">Siguiente</button>
```

Intenté con

```javascript
var input = document.querySelectorAll("#inputtext, #inputtext2")
```

pero no funciona, agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El planteamiento a seguir podría ser el siguiente:

1. El botón "siguiente" parte con estado `disabled`
2. Capturas todos los inputs en una variable a través de la función `querySelectorAll`
3. Recorres mediante un bucle los inputs capturados para añadirles un evento `oninput`.
4. Cada vez que el evento se ejecute, capturamos los valores de los inputs "nombre" y "apellido" para comprobar su longitud. Si la longitud de ambos es superior a 0 entonces activamos el botón siguiente, en caso contrario lo desactivamos.

```js
const b = document.getElementById('button');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("input", displayButton); 
})

function displayButton() {
  const nombre = document.getElementById('inputtext').value
  const apellido = document.getElementById('inputtext2').value
  
  if (nombre.length > 0 && apellido.length > 0) {
    b.disabled = false
  }
  else {
    b.disabled = true
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Nombre">
<input type="text" id="inputtext2" placeholder="Apellido">
<input type="text" id="inputtext3" placeholder="Telefono">

<button id="button" disabled>Siguiente</button>
```

**Referencias:** [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió de ayuda. Como podría agregar un mensaje de error si hago clic en el botón siguiente antes de llenar los campos de nombre y apellido